# Scrollify - Block mouse scroll when animation going

Tags: jquery, browser, jquery-scrollify

I'm using scrollify on my web page and I have a problem when scrolling from one section to another. It all works fine with Firefox, but Chrome and other browsers are causing problems. 1 scroll moves to another section, but when I scroll 2 or more times while animation going, it makes a glitch effect. What I want to make is when animation is triggered to stop mousescroll until animation is over.

Scrollify - https://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/#home

My settings -

```
if( window.innerWidth > 1000 ) {
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $.scrollify({
  section : ".section-full-width",
  interstitialSection: "",
  easing: "easeOutExpo",
  scrollSpeed: 900,
  offset : 1,
  scrollbars: true,
  standardScrollElements: "",
  setHeights: true,
  overflowScroll: true,
  updateHash: true,
  touchScroll:true,
  });
});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this Issue helps solving your Problem:
https://github.com/lukehaas/Scrollify/issues/405

here they talk about the following solutions:

1.Update to the latest version 1.0.21

or

2.add after line 270:

```
wheelHandler: function (e) {
// added
e.preventDefault();
...
}
```

or

3.change line 307:

```
if (locked) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @Shree tnx for the advice, changed the answer and added the possible solutions from the link.